# Simple CSS Edit

Tags: html, css

I have a simple query which I cannot get my head around. I have an image put into my 'nav' div and it contains a red & white box. I have created a 'content' div after the 'nav' div where my content will go but it does not match the length of the image in the previous div. please see [this link](http://www.monsoonsrestaurant.co.uk/spice_of_india/) for a clearer picture.

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="header">
        <!-- LOGO GOES HERE -->
    </div>

    <div id="nav">
        <img src="images/nav.png" width="1076" height="99" />
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        HOW DO I ALIGN THIS DIV TO MATCH THE LENGTH OF THE WHITE BOX ABOVE?
    </div>

</div><!--End of wrap -->
```

```
    body {
    background-color:#d3d1d1;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#wrap {
    width:1076px;
    margin:auto;
}

#content {
    background-color:white;

}
```

Comment: .. give it the same size as `.nav`

Comment: wrap `#nav` and `#content` in a new `div#main` and give all alignment properties to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `#content` add the following properties:

```
width: 1029px (I find it looks better than 1028px, but you can try both)
margin-left: 22px
```

This will make the `#content` box the same size as the white space of your image, and it will align it so they both start at the same point on the left.

Comment: I think this will fail on window resize

Comment: Agreed, although right now the website is not being coded responsive (ie. the image has a fixed width as well). If they were looking to make it resizable, it would be best to use % for the width, instead of px, both on the image in 'nav' and in the 'content'

Answer (score 1):

Put the following rule on `#content`:

```
margin: 0 25px 0 22px;
```

It will still look ugly though since your image has a jagged soft edge on the right. You can compensate for this with a border:

```
#content {
    margin: 0 25px 0 22px;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best idea - remove white space from image and then make the whole thing white. Add top margin, left, right and center the content using margin: 0 auto;

Comment: You mean top `padding`. And the id is `nav` so probably the white space is temporary.

Comment: But adding a white space using image doesn't make sense, when you can easily add using background white and adjust accordingly.

Comment: I mean, he added white space /img just for the time being to see if everything aligns right. It can later be replaced with an actual nav menu. In that case, padding would be, you know, ...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your image is not really centered. The foldy little bits aren't even. So, that is the first issue that might throw my answer off.

```
#content {
  margin: 0 auto; /* this centers the div | 0 margin top/bottom auto on sides */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1030px; /* this needs to be the exact width of your white thing in photoshop */
}
```

That's the simple answer... However... it requires that your photoshop image symmetrical.

Answer (score -1):

Change your #content css to:

```
#content {
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 22px;
  width: 1028px;
}
```

How this works:
The margin is set to align the left side of the content box.
The width is then increased until it matches the white box in the image.

**EDIT**
Removed unnecessary left positioning as pointed out in comments

Comment: Why not just add a margin to the left *and* right then... this approach is overly complex with the relative positioning.

Comment: I usually use SCSS and I like to store the width as a variable that I can use to help determine the width of subelements. So, personal preference.